Chi squared for three different vectors of unequal sample size
I am looking to perform chi-squared on three different vectors which have an unequal sample size.
I have tried to do this as both vectors and combing the data in a dataframe but continue to get error messages including "x" and "y" must have the same length.
I have put some example vectors below / how I have combined into dataframe.
alpha <- c(10,15,20)
bravo <- c(12,18,19,20)
charlie <-c(19,30,21,34,10)

> chisq.test(alpha, bravo, charlie)
Error in chisq.test(alpha, bravo, charlie) : 
  'x' and 'y' must have the same length

max_ln1 <- max(c(length(alpha), length(bravo)))
max_ln2 <- max(c(length(charlie))) 
max_ln<-max(max_ln2,max_ln1) 
df_fem<- data.frame(total = c(alpha,rep(NA, max_ln - length(alpha))), 
                    af = c(bravo,rep(NA, max_ln - length(bravo))), 
                    naive = c(charlie,rep(NA, max_ln - length(charlie))))



The chisq.test function can accept either 1 or 2 arguments for the data. What is your actual hypothesis?

I have a three groups in total and have a selection of characteristics. So, for example, I have a sample number for each group and then the number of females within that group - so I am wanting to see if there is a significant difference in number of females between groups (hope that is clear enough, let me know if not)


You only need one max: max_ln1 <- max(length(alpha), length(bravo), length(charlie)). 2) The explanation in the previous comment is not completely clear to me, each vector represents counts of different characteristics and some vectors record more characteristics than others? Why are they of different lengths?


You'll need to arrange your data in a similar way to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70497840/unequal-group-chi-square-test-in-r?rq=2

Also, see this post on how to solve the immediate problem of binding vectors of different lengths.
